# Nav bar removed, how to remove white space?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I have used [this template](https://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-modern-business/) for one of my projects.

In this project there is no need for a navigation bar so I have removed this code, but now I need to move the carousel to the top of the page, I was hoping to chive this with `.carousel { margin-top:0px !important }` but this was not the solution. How to achieve this?

[image]

Comment: can you post the code sample of the edited one ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give

```
body {
    padding-top: 0px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

change body padding to zero

```
body {
    padding-top: 0px;
}
```